# In jQuery, How to fix containment bug when using resizable() and draggable() simultaneously?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

In jQuery, How do you fix containment bug when using resizable() and draggable() simultaneously?  It seems as though the left offset and top offset of the containment for resizable is buggy if you use draggable on the same object.  I have looked this up on google and a few people had the same problem, but no answers.  If anyone could help it would be great, this is driving me nuts!!

Heres an example:
http://www.fissiondesigns.com/simon/

Try resizing one of boxes on the image.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this bug.  The last comment discusses a fix, so you might try it and see if it helps.  It discusses an issue with top/left positioning.  I had a similar issue using resizable within a scrollable div and this fixed the problem for my use (using 1.7.3).

[ui.resizable - Scroll Jump Around](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/3635)